# insert number in sql database with vb.net (like student ID, Employee ID)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I want to make an auto generating transaction no. in sql database like student ID, or Employee ID every time i insert data in sql database. all i can do now is to insert data. but i dont have idea how to create transaction no. in everytime i add data.

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query = "insert into marketingLog(TransCode,Endorser,Enrollee_Name,Course,Rebates,Trans_Date,CreatedBy,Status)" _
            & "values(@transcode,@endorser,@name,@course,@rebates,@transdate,@user,@status)"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbUse.db)
            conn.Open()
            Using comm As New SqlCommand
                With comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query

                    .Parameters.Add("@endorser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbEndorser.Text 'Endorser
                    .Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEnrolleeName.Text 'Enrolle_Name
                    .Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCourse.Text 'Course
                    .Parameters.Add("@rebates", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblRebate.Text 'Rebates
                    .Parameters.Add("@transdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateAndTime.Now
                    .Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUsername.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Standby"
                End With
                Try
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    conn.Close()
                    loadmyGrid()
                    loadDefault()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

TransCode is my column name. i want to add like 1,2,3,4,5 every transaction. i use it as my transaction no.

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: make it as auto increment

Comment: Just add an auto-increment column to your SQL table then?  Not sure what's difficult about this one...

Answer (score 1):

What could you problely do before insert data into the table you find the

```
Select Max(TranCode) From marketingLog
```

and it will return some int number or 0 for the first time.

you just increment it with 1.

and then perform your insert.

actually i don't know how to code in vb but i am trying to write logic in your code please refer it and try to apply using vb

for e.g.

```
    Dim query As String = String.Empty

    query = "Select Max(TranCode) From marketingLog";

    Dim dtb As New DataTable;

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbUse.db)
    conn.Open()

    Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    dad.Fill(dtb)

    Dim intTransNo As Integer  =  Int32.Parse(dtb.Rows(0)(0).ToString()) + 1;

    query = "insert into marketingLog(TransCode,Endorser,Enrollee_Name,Course,Rebates,Trans_Date,CreatedBy,Status)" _
        & "values(@transcode,@endorser,@name,@course,@rebates,@transdate,@user,@status)"


        Using comm As New SqlCommand
            With comm
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = query
                .Parameters.Add("@transcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = intTransNo
                .Parameters.Add("@endorser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbEndorser.Text 'Endorser
                .Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEnrolleeName.Text 'Enrolle_Name
                .Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCourse.Text 'Course
                .Parameters.Add("@rebates", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblRebate.Text 'Rebates
                .Parameters.Add("@transdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateAndTime.Now
                .Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUsername.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Standby"
            End With
            Try
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                loadmyGrid()
                loadDefault()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: can you please give me some codes from my work, i really dont get how do i start in this part(adding transaction number like student ID)

Comment: please help, i dont know how to code in this part. all i know is inserting data, but when it comes to what they called "auto increment something" for my transno.

Comment: this is my final effort friend i have written some code over there which i have not tested but you can test it yourself. i have writtn this code by googling. please try to implement logic by self

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

You can use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in your table. you don't need to specify any data for  this column. Data for this column will be automatically inserted on new record insert.

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('Lars','Monsen')
```

[Check the fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35f47/1)

Your Code:  You simply need to skip putting data into the Auto_Increment column.

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty

    //query = "Select Max(TranCode) From marketingLog";

    Dim dtb As New DataTable;

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbUse.db)
    conn.Open()


    query = "insert into marketingLog(Endorser,Enrollee_Name,Course,Rebates,Trans_Date,CreatedBy,Status)" _
        & "values(@endorser,@name,@course,@rebates,@transdate,@user,@status)"


        Using comm As New SqlCommand
            With comm
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = query
                                .Parameters.Add("@endorser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbEndorser.Text 'Endorser
                .Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEnrolleeName.Text 'Enrolle_Name
                .Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCourse.Text 'Course
                .Parameters.Add("@rebates", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblRebate.Text 'Rebates
                .Parameters.Add("@transdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateAndTime.Now
                .Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUsername.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Standby"
            End With
            Try
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                loadmyGrid()
                loadDefault()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```